# My 11 yr old daughter wants to be a boy

Tags: pre-teen, girls, transition

My daughter came out as "transgender" to me  and my husband in a family therapy session. I don't want to call her by her "preferred pronouns" of he/him because if it's a phase i'll be making a fool of myself. She also wants to change her name? What do i do, should i just wait this out?

Comment: Hi and welcome! If te duplicate is unhelpful, please edit your post to specify how your problem is different and what your goals are in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: I ofen adress my kids with the pronoun "you". When I have to use a 3rd person pronoun, they're often not around